# How to handle multiple requests to purchase at same time

Tags: node.js, database

Let's imagine we have a shopping website which the users are able to purchase items with their account-balance.

user A requests to purchase item B.

here are the steps:

- Database gets user's balance.
- Checks if balance is more than the cost.
- Updates user's balance ( `balance - cost = newBalance` )

now this is where my question begins:

since javascript is single-threaded and we are requesting to db in an asynchronous way what happens if:

- user A sends multiple requests to purchase the item
- another user tries to purchase the item ( item should be out of stock after 1 purchase )

I've done some testing and I want to know what is the best way to prevent userA to purchase multiple items when in reality he should be out of balance after second purchase?

my test:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const cost = 500;

// .data.txt has `1000` as its content
function getMoneyFromDatabase() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./data.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(Number(data));
    });
  });
}

function setMoneyToDatabase(newMoney) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile('./data.txt', newMoney, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve();
    });
  });
}

async function getMoney() {
  const money = await getMoneyFromDatabase();
  if (money >= cost) {
    // Able to purchase
    console.log('able to purchase');
    const newMoney = money - cost;
    await setMoneyToDatabase(newMoney);
    console.log('purchased');
  }
}

getMoney();
getMoney();
getMoney();
getMoney();
```

this logs 4 `purchased` while in reality it should only be able to purchase two times
and the data saved inside `data.txt` is 500 while it should be -1000 ( 500, 0, -500, -1000 )

Comment: This is where you need atomic operations in your database.  It's a race condition to request the balance, check it and then set it as two different database operations.  That's not atomic and can lead to race condition problems with other requests.  You need an atomic operation in your database that decrements the total or returns an error if the balance is not sufficient.  Or, in some databases, you use locks.  How to do that in any given database is specific to that database, but since it's such a common database issue, it should have a capability like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is make sure your API requests related to charging are idempotent, meaning they can be sent multiple times but will result in the same outcome as long as the request is the same.

You can implement idempotent requests by sending a unique key along with the request to make sure that only the first time it will be accepted as a new request otherwise it will be handled as a duplicate request. This is also useful when you want to safely retry a requests without accidentally charging the user multiple times.

Many payment processors have built-in support for this such as Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests

As for stock, you should only decrease it when a payment is verified or if it's not automatic the first user with a pending invoice for it. Otherwise the stock will go down even if the user for example has the balance but payment could not be processed.

Implementing payments is hard and can only be learned to be implemented in a decent way after trial and errors, I'd recommend you try to do a minimal app and handle payments with a payment gateway such as Stripe and advance by handling edge cases.

Comment: How to handle decrease there is 1 item and 2 payments were verified? Like a race condition?